# Getting an undefined error in my for-loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, undefined

I am trying to make a sorting algorithm visualizer.

I have a `bubbleSort()` function below and the array is fixed at a length of 3. It doesn't work fully yet, but when I execute bubbleSort, it should make the elements in the array turn red (visualized as a green 'bar' turning red) as it processes them. The problem is that, when j gets to 2 in the for-loop, it throws an error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined"

```
function bubbleSort(array) {
    let len = array.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            
            // Highlight the two bars we are comparing in red, doesn't work atm
            const arrayBars = document.getElementsByClassName('bar'); //Is a list of all elements
            const barA = arrayBars[j].style; 
            const barB = arrayBars[j + 1].style; //Causes error when j = 2
            barA.backgroundColor = "red";
            barB.backgroundColor = "red";

            if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) { //When j = 2 why does it not give error?

                // Psuedo code: If j > (j + 1), swap the height

                let tmp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j + 1];
                array[j + 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
```

I believe the error is caused by the line below since you can't create a constant for j[3] as j[3] does not exist.

```
// const barB = arrayBars[j + 1].style; //Causes error when j = 2
```

But if that's the case, why is it that the below line doesn't error out when j = 2? Should it not also error out because j[3] doesn't exist?

```
if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) { //When j = 2 why does it not give error?
```

Comment: _"But if that's the case, why is it..."_ - Because in that case you don't try to access a property of the element at index `j + 1` which will be `undefined` for `j > 1`. It would also throw an error if you would try to access `.toString()`: `console.log(array[j + 1].toString())`

Comment: Because in the if block `if (array[j] > array[j + 1])` it is basically comparing two undefined values so it is like `if (undefined > undefined)` which is allowed. But accessing something over an undefined value is surely going to throw an error since `undefined.style` doesn't exists.

Comment: The elements with class `bar` don't change while the loops are running, so the line `const arrayBars = ...` should be outside of any loop. And even if they would change, `.getElementsByClassName()` returns a live `HTMLColletion` which will be updated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Change "j < len" to "j < len -1", so if len is 3, j will be max 1 and j+1 will be max 2.

```
function bubbleSort(array) {
    let len = array.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < len -1; j++) {
            
            // Highlight the two bars we are comparing in red, doesn't work atm
            const arrayBars = document.getElementsByClassName('bar'); //Is a list of all elements
            const barA = arrayBars[j].style; 
            const barB = arrayBars[j + 1].style; //Causes error when j = 2
            barA.backgroundColor = "red";
            barB.backgroundColor = "red";

            if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) { //When j = 2 why does it not give error?

                // Psuedo code: If j > (j + 1), swap the height

                let tmp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j + 1];
                array[j + 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
```